# Tuckey url rewrite with spring boot, angular 4 results in strange error?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat8, angular4-router, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to configure tuckey URL rewrite for spring boot + angular 4 app.

Routing on angular 4 looks like this

```
{ 
    path: 'media-detail/:media-name', component: MediaDetailComponent
}
```

and in urlrewrite.xml as this

```
<rule match-type="wildcard">
    <from>/media-detail/([a-z]+)$</from>
    <to >../index.html</to>
</rule>
```

But on page reload, I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

in all the .bundle.js files.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Do you have a solution to this??

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in this domain. I focused on readability, that is all I can contribute here ;-(